# Use ngx-translate in component

Tags: javascript, angular, ngx-translate

I'm using ngx-translate with no-problems in views, using pipes. What i need to do is to use it in a component, for example to show an error message, or define a datatable column default content.

I'm trying to do something like:

```
translate.instant("AREA.NEW");
```

or

```
translate.get("AREA.NEW").subscribe((res: string) => {
    console.log(res);
});
```

I've tried calling it in ngOnInit() and ngAfterViewInit()

But in both cases i just get "AREA.NEW", not the translated word. I asume the json dictionary is loaded after my call, so i don't realize how make it work.

Comment: The subscibe  in the translate.get() observable should give value if  "AREA.NEW" is found. Does the console.log(res) still return AREA.NEW? if so verify it's really defined in your transate definition?

Comment: Can you post the whole code? Imports, injection and method where you call the TranslateService.

Comment: I will try. @FetraR. it's defined. If do a $(document).ready and inside it any of the options above, it shows the correct translation (after the json is loaded).

Comment: for me this works in ngoninit using get + subscribe. it will only return the key without translating, if the key does not exist in the translations.

Answer (score 19):

Import the **TranslateService** and use it wherever you want.

```
import { TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';

export class YourComponent {
  constructor(private translateService: TranslateService) {
    console.log('translation', this.translateService.instant('my_i18n_json_defined_key'));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

It's work.

```
constructor(private readonly translateService: TranslateService) { }

ngOnInit() {
    this.translateService.get(['']).subscribe(translations => {
        console.info(this.translateService.instant('key1'));
        console.info(this.translateService.instant('key2'));
        console.info(this.translateService.instant('key3'));
    });
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 2):

Another cause for "instant" translation not working can be the translations not being available when required. This might happen when translations are loaded using the TranslateHttpLoader (example [here](https://github.com/ngx-translate/core)) which loads from translation files in an async way.

One trick to overcome this is shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54244011/2780791) (just tested and it works in Angular 13+) and forces the component to wait until the translation is ready by adding a special resolver on its route:

#### The resolver

```
@Injectable()
export class TranslationLoaderResolver {

    constructor(private translate: TranslateService){ }

    resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<any>{
        return this.translate.get("does.not.matter"); 
    }
}
```

#### Routing usage

```
{path: "segment", component: YourComponent, resolve: {model: TranslationLoaderResolver}
```