# ngx-translate usage in typescript Angular

Tags: angular, ngx-translate

I'm using this @ngx-translate/core and @ngx-translate/http-loader i18n service and it works fine in templates (.html)

```
{{'title'|translate}}
```

Now I want to translate in my component typescript file (.ts) but I don't know how to use it.

I inject the translateService in contructor

```
constructor(private translate: TranslateService) {}
```

.component.ts

```
//update employee
editClick(item){
console.log(item);
this.emp=item;
this.ModalTitle="Edit Employee";  <-- Need to translate this using pipe
this.ActivateAddEditEmpComp=true;
}

//delete employee
deleteClick(item){
if(confirm('Are you sure??')){  <-- Need to translate this using pipe
  this.service.deleteEmployee(item.EmployeeId).subscribe(data=>{
    alert(data.toString());
    this.refreshEmpList();
  })
}
}
```

Comment: Check this:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155989/ngx-translate-with-dynamic-text-on-ts-file

Comment: `this.translate.instant('property.field')`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use ngx-translate in component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45314618/use-ngx-translate-in-component)

Comment: @HarunYilmaz yes

Answer (score 1):

First import translate service

```
import { TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';
```

Injext in the constructor:

```
constructor(
    public translate: TranslateService,
  )
```

And you can create a function or however you wanted to use inline you can do something like this.

```
translationMsg(key) {
    this.translate.get('key').subscribe((data) => {
      return data;
    });
  }
```

**For your use case you can do this**

```
this.ModalTitle = this.translationMsg('Edit_Employee');
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use **instant** or you can use the get method and later can subscribe.

```
this.ModalTitle = this.translate.instant('EDIT_EMPLOYEE')
```

Second Approach :

```
this.translate.get('EDIT_EMPLOYEE').subscribe((data) => {
  this.ModalTitle = data;
});
```